# Understanding InnoDB Locking and Transaction Model

Tags: mysql, multithreading, transactions, innodb, race-condition

Recently we had a discussion about how to tackle race conditions and I would like two know if my understanding of the locking and transaction model in innodb is correct in the following case (or what I might missing):

Given the following database table:

```
CREATE TABLE `requests` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('queuing','processing') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'queuing',
  `pid` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

having 3 records r1, r2 and r3 in this table, (all three with status queuing and pid = null) and two processes P1 and P2.

P1 runs the following query two assign the next queuing entry to itself.

```
UPDATE requests SET status = 'processing', pid = '1' 
WHERE status = 'queuing' 
AND pid IS NULL 
ORDER BY id 
LIMIT 1;
```

This will set an exclusive record lock for T1 in r1.

Now P2 runs the update query

```
UPDATE requests 
SET status = 'processing', pid = '2' 
WHERE status = 'queuing' 
AND pid IS NULL 
ORDER BY id 
LIMIT 1;
```

and requests the exclusive record lock for r1 as well. As this is currently held by T1, the lock will not be granted to T2 -> T2 waits until T1 is committed

P1 runs

```
SELECT * FROM requests WHERE status = 'processing' AND pid = '1';
```

and fetches r1.
P1 commits T1 and the change made to r1 gets visible for everybody.

T2 continues and as r1 is has now status processing and pid != null, the update is run for r2.
P2 selects r2 and commits the transaction T2 - the change made to r2 gets visible to everybody.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `INT(15)` is a really odd thing to see since that type can only represent 11 digits at best.

Comment: Sounds right to me.  Assuming you only have one row as processing, you don't tell need a transaction around the update and select, since both queries only update where status is queueing.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than answer the question as asked, I am going to address the root question:  "This lock is giving me trouble; what can I do about it?"

```
INDEX(status, pid, id)
```

Probably what is happening is that you are having to scan rather far in the table, meanwhile blocking others.  With this index, it should be able to drill down the BTree to the next item much faster.  "Faster" implies less chance of deadlock.

A drawback is that the new index needs a messy update.

My mantra is "Don't queue it, just do it."  By this I mean that there may be more overhead in building a queuing mechanism in MySQL than benefit.

Also, run the `UPDATE` in its own transaction, not part of some bigger chunk of code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - the index is a good point. Actually the lock isn't giving me trouble. I just wanted to clarify whether this approach solves the race condition problem or not.

But what is the advantage of having the update in it's own trnsaction rather then together with the following Select?

Comment: @Ferdi - Put things together in a transaction whenever another transaction could sneak in between them and mess things up.  (I'm unclear on whether your case is such.)

Comment: @Ferdi - My attitude on race, etc, is to make _transactions_ as fast as practical -- to minimize conflicts.  _And_ to check for errors (especially deadlocks) because they _will_ occur.  Trying to understand the details and nuances of gap locking, race conditions, etc, tends to fry my brain.